# Environment variables from launchsettings.json are being used in tests?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops

I have a .NET Core build pipeline that is used to run some tests on Azure DevOps. Settings for each environment are stored in configuration files such as:

- `appsettings.json`
- `appsettings.qa.json`
- `appsettings.test.json`

Build is very basic - it contains a `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build` and `dotnet test` tasks:

[image: Build definition]

The `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable is set in the **Variables** section of the build pipeline:

[image: Build variables]

These builds are running on VMs that contains multiple build agents (private, not hosted).

Now the weird part - **sometimes the build is picking up the wrong settings!**.

After some investigation and adding more logging we realized that `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value sometimes is `Development-Selfhost`, instead of `QA`. That value seems to come from the `launchsettings.json` file of a project that is referenced by the tests project:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyProject.PublicApi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development-Selfhost"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5028/"
    }
  }
}
```

According to [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1), `launchSettings.json` file is used when an app is launched with `dotnet run`:

> `launchSettings.json` is read if available. `environmentVariables` settings in `launchSettings.json` override environment variables.

Adding the `launchSettings.json` to `.gitignore` solves my issue, but I'm trying to understand why it's using these settings if I don't execute a `dotnet run` command in my build pipeline. Also, why is this behaviour so random? Sometimes it uses the right settings, sometimes it doesn't.

### UPDATE 1 (13/12/2019):

I've checked the logs and I can confirm file `launchSettings.json` is copied into the `bin` folder of the test project.

I've tried setting a different value for `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` that is not set anywhere else:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyProject.PublicApi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Rui"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5028/"
    }
  }
}
```

Behaviour is basically the same - sometimes it uses the value set in the pipeline and other times it will use the value set in `launchSettings.json` and will fail, because there is no correspondent configuration file:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : The configuration file 'appsettings.Rui.base.json' was not found and is not optional.

Comment: Since your builds are self-hosted, could other builds be running at the same time that overwrite that env variable?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes that's the first thing that came to my mind, i.e. `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` being modified somewhere while the build was running. The thing is that I set a task to display that variable value at the beginning and end of the build but the value is the same, in this case `QA`

Comment: Also, value `Development-Selfhost` is not set in any pipelines, only in the source code - in this particular build, in the `launchsettings.json`

Comment: Could you please tell us where did you see the value of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, from the Artifact's file or the log in build pipeline?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I see the value of `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in the task log (`dotnet test`) - in the C# code we're retrieving this value using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")`

Comment: The pipeline just executes commands, there cannot be random behavior there to pick different settings. Are you sure the correct commit was checked out when you saw the wrong value in the logs? You can check in the folder where the code was cloned to, whether the launchsettings.json exists there. In that case, that's the problem. Otherwise I would check on which VMs the log indicates the wrong value. I would login to that VM to see what the environment variable values are. If the value is wrong in the env var then this requires checking further why it was not overwritten.

Comment: @tubakaya I can confirm that this weird issue occurs without any code changes. I can also confirm that `launchSettings.json` is copied to the `bin` folder of the test project - see my update

Comment: Is there anything in your `.csproj` file that makes it copy the `launchSettings.json`? What does it say in Solution Explorer when you select the file? See in Properties under *Copy to Output Directory*.

Comment: @silkfire I don't believe that's relevant, I already found a workaround for my problem. What I'm trying to understand is why this is happening so "randomly" - according to the documentation `launchSettings.json` file is used when an app is launched with `dotnet run` command, which is not used in the build pipeline.

Comment: In that case I'd file a bug report to the ASP.NET Core team over at https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore as this probably isn't intended.

Comment: Sorry I understood it wrong. I thought after you added launchsettings.json to .gitignore that you still had the problem. But the problem was solved. Can you check whether the problem did and did not occur on specific VMs? It can be a caching issue on the VM. Given environment variables overwrite the values and environment variables are stored on VM, this might turn out to be an issue of caching on the server. Although I get your point that there should be no difference. Each execution should set the environment var values. Maybe there is a mistake in the tasks where this is enforced.

Comment: @tubakaya this issue occurs in at least 2 different VMs.

Comment: It can occur on 2 different VMs, that doesn't refute the theory. If on those 2 VMs it consistently occurred and on other VMs it didn't, then there is a clue there. Or on the same VM did it sometimes occur and sometimes not?

Comment: @tubakaya behaviour is "random" even within a specific VM, i.e. some builds are ok and some are not in both VMs

Answer (score 3):

I too faced the similar issue but in my case environment variables in  "launchSettings.json" always were overriding other configurations.

I solved it by setting up multiple profiles in launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "grpc-server": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:5001"
    },
    "staging-profile": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
    },
    "live-profile": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:80"
    }
  }
}
```

and passing the profile name with

```
dotnet run --launch-profile {profile-name}
```

Comment: Is it work in a pipeline stage?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a test, maybe more than one, that is starting and running an application. That would cause launch settings to be read and environment variables to be set durring the dotnet test task. That would explain:

1. How your environement variables are being overriden
2. How the following exception was thrown

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : The configuration file 'appsettings.Rui.base.json' was not found and is not optional.

Comment: `dotnet test` task is only running selenium tests.

Comment: selenium is a UI testing framework, so those tests will need a running application